# Flutter App gradle build failing after adding flutter_contact plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

My Flutter app was working fine. But failing now after I added the flutter_contact 0.5.3 package.

Please find the gradle Stack trace

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@53232d9e' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log >output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Kindly Help

Answer (score 0):

  -

---

---

- flutter channel stable
- flutter upgrade --force
- flutter pub cache repair
- cd
- flutter clean

This will probably solve your question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Used IOBit Unlocker to unlock the project folder - then ran flutter clean. Everything builds fine now)

IOBit Unlocker: https://ru.iobit.com/iobit-unlocker.php

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just run `flutter run` inside the project folder and it was solved.